# Java referencing a class in the same directory

Tags: java, class, import, package

I created a `Pair` class in Java (similar to the c++ pair) and am having trouble referencing it from a different java file. I am working inside a Java file, let's call it `fileA` in the same directory as `Pair.class.` 
Additionally, I have written `package current-directory` at the top of both files.

However, when I try `javac fileA` all my errors are `cannot find symbol` and the little arrow points to my custom `Pair` type.

How do I get the java compiler to see `Pair.class` inside of `fileA`?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Attached the package structure here

Comment: Learn how java packages and import work. That has the solution for your problem.

Comment: If you are compiling the fileA it should be done by the command 'javac fileA.java' i.e. with .java extension. Whereas to run it use java fileA without any extension.

Answer (score 20):

Java is driven by some basic conventions, including that directory structure follows package structure, and java files are named after the classes they define.

You should have defined fileA as a class inside of fileA.java like so:

```
public class fileA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair p = new Pair(0, 1);
        System.out.println("a is "+p.a+" and b is "+p.b);
    }
}
```

and a corresponding Pair class:

```
public class Pair {
    public final int a;
    public final int b;
    public Pair(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

If you are calling javac from within the same directory as both java files, you should not declare a package at the top, as they are within the 'default package'. As such, the above should work.

Using the default package provides some convenience but also some restrictions which I won't elaborate on, but now that you know about the default package you can look it up. I recommend using package names, which is as simple as adding, as you did, something like:

```
package kugathasan;
```

at the beginning of each file. If you do this though, you should put both files in a directory called kugathasan and call javac from the directory containing kugathasan.

Answer (score 4):

It is a package structure issue. You may understand by seeing this screenshot how they look in my IDE and in folder.

[image]

And in the folder, they look like this.

[image]

And in code, they have this package.

```
package com.jini;
```

Hope you get the idea how this works.

Answer (score 4):

If they are in the same directory,
You need to compile both classes at the same sentence;

javac fileA.java pair.java

Answer (score 0):

technocrat's comment is correct.

In Java, you don't normally work directly with the .class files when developing your application.  You work with the .java files.  The packages that you create in your IDE should contain your .java files.

So instead of putting Pair.class inside the same package directory as fileA.java, put Pair.java in it.  You should then have a directory/package that contains both fileA.java and Pair.java