# How to resolve "main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol" error in Java?

Tags: java

main.java file

```
package animal;
    class Main {    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
    
            animal dog = new animal();
            dog.bark();
        }
    
    }
```

animal.java file

```
public class animal {
    void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof-Woof");
    }
}
```

The error I am getting.

[image]

Can someone please help, I am new to java?

Comment: Did you import the `animal` class?

Comment: yes, I wrote "package animal;"

Comment: if your file is main.java, your class shouldn't be called Main. did you compile your animal class? is it in the same package?

Comment: @user9521030 package animal doesn't import anything. are both classes in that package? if not, you'll need to import it in the main class

Comment: both the classes are in same folder.

Comment: @user9521030 folder and package are not the same. do both of them have package animal; ? are both compiled?

Comment: You had to compile both the class and then run your program.

Comment: actually, I am using visual studio code. And this is my directory hierarchy.



sololearn
  -main.java
  -animal.java

Comment: You still have to import it

Comment: to import animal class, i have to write "package animal;" in my main.java file, correct?

Comment: I have edited my code above, have a look at it.

Comment: @user9521030 no, you are putting main in an animal package, while animal is left in the default package. in order to import something, you'll need to use an import statement

Comment: I have made the changes based on the suggestion you all gave but I am still getting an error, please have a look at it.  http://collabedit.com/hk2ak

Comment: Did you put the "package animal" statement at the top of animal.java?

Comment: *"To import animal class, i have to write "package animal;" in my main.java file, correct?"* -  Incorrect!  Seriously, I think you need to go back to your textbook, lecture handouts or the tutorial that you are using and reread the parts about packages and importing.  If your English is good, the official Oracle Java Tutorial is recommended: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try remove **package animal;** from your Main.java file

**So change your code from this:**

```
package animal;   
    class Main {    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
    
            animal dog = new animal();
            dog.bark();
        }
    
    }
```

**TO become like that:**

```
class Main {    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
    
            animal dog = new animal();
            dog.bark();
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `package` because your animal file is not a package but just a class

```
class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        animal dog = new animal();
        dog.bark();
    }

}
```

This link can help you to understand [Java referencing a class in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669272/java-referencing-a-class-in-the-same-directory)

But if want still using `package`, you can do like this:

```
//save by A.java  
package pack;  
public class A {  
    public void msg() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }  
}  

//save by B.java  
package mypack;  
class B {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        pack.A obj = new pack.A();  //using fully qualified name  
        obj.msg();  
    }  
}
```

src: [https://www.studytonight.com/java/package-in-java.php#:~:text=To%20import%20java%20package%20into,by%20directly%20using%20its%20name](https://www.studytonight.com/java/package-in-java.php#:%7E:text=To%20import%20java%20package%20into,by%20directly%20using%20its%20name).

Comment: don't change to import, just delete the package statement